# Lifecycle callback postUpdate to send an email in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, email, event-listener, lifecycle

I'm trying to send an email when the entity is updating (and getVerified), I used the event Suscriber from doctrine, but I don't know exactly how to do that.

My MailEvent.php :

```
class MailEvent
 {
// the entity listener methods receive two arguments:
// the entity instance and the lifecycle event
public function postUpdate(Candidature $candidature, Annonce $annonce, MailerInterface $mailer, LifecycleEventArgs $event): void
{   
$change = $event->getEntityChangeSet();

if ($change instanceof Candidature and $candidature->getIsVerified()) {
    $email = (new Email())
        ->from('trtconseilexample@gmail.com')
        ->to($annonce->getEmail())
        ->subject('Vous avez un nouveau candidat !')
        ->text("{$candidature->getNom()} {$candidature->getPrenom()} a postulé à votre annonce, vous trouverez son CV en pièce jointe !")
        ->attachFromPath("public/uploads/images/{$candidature->getCv()}");
    ;
    $mailer->send($email);
}
}
```

If someone can help me understand, thank you.

EDIT: Problem solve!  Thank you all !
MailEvent.php:

```
class MailEvent
{
  // the entity listener methods receive two arguments:
  // the entity instance and the lifecycle event

public function postUpdate(Candidature $candidature, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

     $entityManager = $this->entityManager;

    $annonce = $entityManager->getRepository(Annonce::class)->findOneBy([
       'id' => $request->get('id')
   ]);


    if ($candidature->getIsVerified()) {
    $email = (new Email())
    ->from('trtconseilexample@gmail.com')
    ->to($annonce->getEmail())
    ->subject('Vous avez un nouveau candidat !')
    ->text("{$candidature->getNom()} {$candidature->getPrenom()} a postulé à votre annonce, vous trouverez son CV en pièce jointe !")
    ->attachFromPath("public/uploads/images/{$candidature->getCv()}");
;
$this->mailer->send($email);
    }

}

public function __construct(
    private readonly EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
    private readonly MailerInterface $mailer,
    private readonly RequestStack $requestStack
){

}
```

}

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with that code? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Create an [Doctrine Event Subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers) as explained here, it should be what you're looking for.

Comment: It's returning me an error : Too few arguments to function App\EventListener\MailEvent::postUpdate(),

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you register your listener in your `services.yaml`

```yaml
    App\EventListener\MailEvent:
        tags:
            - name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener'
              event: 'postUpdate'
              entity: 'App\Entity\Candidature'
```

Then you need the postUpdate function inside your listener,

```php
    public function postUpdate(Candidature $candidature, LifecycleEventArgs $event): void
    {
...
    }
```

It can only take 2 parameters, if you need access to services you need to use the dependency injection in the constructor :

```php
    public function __construct(
        private readonly AnnonceRepository $annonceRepository,
        private readonly MailerInterface $mailer,
    ) {
    }
```

Then you can use these inside your postUpdate function, I do not know how you get the related `Annonce` in your project but you could use the repository to go and fetch it from the database.

```php
    public function postUpdate(Candidature $candidature, LifecycleEventArgs $event): void
    {
       //maybe ?
    $annonce = $this->annonceRepository->findOneBy["candidature" => $candidature];

//This has to be a Candidature entity, as defined in the services.yaml, so no need to check that, you also do not use the changeset at all so no need for that either 

if ($candidature->getIsVerified()) {
    $email = (new Email())
        ->from('trtconseilexample@gmail.com')
        ->to($annonce->getEmail())
        ->subject('Vous avez un nouveau candidat !')
        ->text("{$candidature->getNom()} {$candidature->getPrenom()} a postulé à votre annonce, vous trouverez son CV en pièce jointe !")
        ->attachFromPath("public/uploads/images/{$candidature->getCv()}");
    ;
    $this->mailer->send($email);
    }
```